# How to create job in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I want to create job that can run my stored procedure automatically by schedule. And I have completed all the information and do everything that it require. but then I click OK to finish it. And it shown message like this:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SimpleObjectKey' to type
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.JobObjectKey'.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Please, help me...

Thanks you in advance

Comment: you need to be more specific.

Comment: Not **nearly enough** info - what are you trying to do? In what context? When does this error appear?

Comment: You will need to post some code which exhibits this error in order for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: To find missing SQL Server job, log on to the actual SQL server instead. http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View0EBC0EBE-0701-4038-BA9B-15A67A18321B.htm

Answer (score 2):

Simply pasting the error in a google search shows this is a known problem and seems to be fixed in SP2.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/e7c0e73e-8d4b-4624-a19e-352a69995f9e/

Comment: I found that I must reinstall it.